# Finding the largest factor of a number in swift using loops

Tags: swift, loops

I am currently trying to create a code in swift playground that finds the 2nd largest factor (not the number itself) of a number while using a loop. I've figured out how to display all factors of a number, but is there a simple way to have it only deliver one?

ex: for '15' it would be '5'

thanks!

update with code:

```
var number = 15

for i in 2...number {
    if number % i == 0 {
        while (number % i == 0) {
            number /= i
            }
            print(i)
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far.. im a beginning learner (3 weeks into the class)

Comment: You should include your code where you find all factors and see if it can be modified to give only one (probably will).

Comment: You must tried some code, please don't hesitate to provide it!

Comment: Show how you are displaying all factors.

Comment: Are you talking about prime factors? The given number times one is the obvious solution. You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: The _largest factor_ of a number is very trivial, it is the number itself. Please clarify, you want the second largest factor? Or the largest prime factor?

Comment: @OOPer Hi! I'm trying to find the second largest factor. I.e. for '15' I'm trying to display only '5'. With the code above it produces '5' and '3'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the second largest factor, the last factor except `number` itself, is the largest.

Ignoring efficiency, this code would work:

```
var number = 15

var theSecondLargestFactor: Int = 1
for i in 2..<number { //Ignore the largest factor `number` itself
    if number % i == 0 {
        //Replace `theSecondLargestFactor` when a larger factor is found
        theSecondLargestFactor = i
    }
}
print(theSecondLargestFactor) //->5
```

This code outputs `50` when `number` is `100`, as `50` is the second largest factor of `100`. If it is not the expected output, what you want is not *the second largest factor*.

---

In case you want the largest prime factor, again ignoring efficiency:

```
var number = 100

var theLargestPrimeFactor: Int = 1
for i in 2...number { //The `number` itself may be the largest prime factor, so include it
    while number % i == 0 {
        number /= i
        theLargestPrimeFactor = i
    }
}
print(theLargestPrimeFactor) //->5
```

This seems to be more like your code.